# Every "INSERT" query check a combination of column's records

Tags: mysql, database-design, stored-procedures, schema, insert

Unfortunately, my mind has stacked right now and i would like to design a really simple DB schema.

*What i want?*

In a simple table, for instance Table1, there are two different columns, Series and Orders.

I would like every new record for Orders be unique for Series.

> Series: A Orders: 1,2,3,4,5,6
>
> Series: B Orders: 1,2,3,4,5,6

If the user try to insert Series A and Orders 1 for second time i would like to have an **error**.

I think that the best way is using **stored procedure**? Am I right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would it be something like: Series A (Orders 1), Series B (Orders 2). If you try to insert Series A (Orders 1), you can't, right? Why not use a unique index?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are looking for is a "unique" constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD UNIQUE(Series, Orders)
```

That will cause an error to be raised when you try create a row (by inserting new or updating an existing one) that duplicates an existing combination of `Series` and `Order`.

Depending on the rest of the database design, these columns might be a good candidate for a compound primary key which would also enforce uniqueness.

This is fundamentally basic database stuff, I would suggest you grab an introductory book or find a good tutorial online. Keywords that you should understand: `primary key`, `foreign key`, `check constraint`, `unique constraint`, `surrogate key`